# Migration from flask to fastapi

Tags: python, fastapi

I have an application running using flask and I am sending some data in body. Below is my code.

```
    @app.route('/<string:sr>/<string:file>', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def home(sr, file):
    if request.method == "POST":
        # the post request sent contains id, dbuser, dbauth, ruser as form data.
        rid = request.form.get('id')
        duser = request.form.get('dbuser')
        dpwd = request.form.get('dbauth')
        ruser = request.form.get('ruser')
```

I am not able to find how to get this in fastapi

```
from fastapi import FastAPI, Request, Form
import HeapParser
import urllib3
import os
from datetime import datetime
import uvicorn

@app.post('/')
async def root(request: Request):
    print(ctime())
    form = await request.form()
    print(form)
```

Using this Curl query:

```
curl --location --request POST 'https://x.x.x.x/' \
--form 'rid="sdf"' \
--form 'dbuser="asdf"' \
--form 'dbauth="asdfasdf"' \
--form 'ruser="asldhjflas"'
```

Comment: It's well explained on the docs https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/body/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to make this work with below code:

```
@app.post('/')
def lower_case(sr: str = Form(...), file: str = Form(...), dbuser: str = Form(...), dbauth: str = Form(...), ruser: str = Form(...), rid: str = Form(...)):
    print(ctime())
    print(sr)
    print(file)
    print(rid)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it's better to create a pydantic model for post body request. It's more validated way to secure a post request.

```
class FormBody(BaseModel):
rid: int
dbuser: str
dbauth: str
ruser: str

@app.post("/")
async def default_post(form: FormBody):
 print(form.rid)
 print(form.dbuser)
 print(form.dbauth)
 print(form.ruser)
 return form
```